# Add only one input filter to a textarea using form api

Tags: 7, forms, input-formats

I have created a custom form, in which I have one textarea field with a wysiwyg.
Here is the code

```
$form['text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('text'),
    '#title' => t('text'),
    '#format' => NULL,
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
```

So it returns me a textarea field with a format dropdown. Which I don't required. I need only to use the `filtered_html` and the format dropdown should not appear.

Answer (score 1):

There are several  way to  achieve this, you can use the [Hide Formats module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_formats):

> Hide Formats allows you to collapse the "text format" or "input
>   format" dropdowns to clean up the UI.

or [Better Formats module](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats):

> Better formats is a module to add more flexibility to Drupal's core input format system. Features 8.x & 7.x (needs more testing for a stable release)
>
> - Set allowed text formats per field.
> - Set default order of text formats per field.
> - Hide format tips per role. Hide more format tips link per role.
> - Hide format selection per role per entity.
> - **Currently only works on Field API fields on fieldable entities implementing core style text processing.** The good thing is that is
>     most things in core and contrib.

Or, use the FormAPI to disable it with something like:

```
// hook_form_alter function
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // We want this on a specific node type
    if ($form_id == 'NODE_TYPE_node_form') {
        $form['#after_build'][] = 'CUSTOM_MODULE_NODE_TYPE_node_form_after_build';
    }
}

// afterbuild function
function CUSTOM_MODULE_NODE_TYPE_node_form_after_build($form) {
    // We want this on a specific field
    $form['YOUR_FIELD']['und']['0']['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
    return $form;
}
```

**Also** you can try this (I didn't test it but it may work):

```
$form['text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('text'),
    '#title' => t('text'),
    '#format' => "full_html",
    'format'=>array('#access'=> false),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
$form['somename']['somesuffix'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('somename'),
  '#description' => '',
  '#default_value' => '',
  '#rows' => 6,        
);
$form['somename']['format'] = filter_form(FILTER_FORMAT_DEFAULT, NULL, array('somename', 'format'));
```